# Let that be a reminder

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Employee: *Where's Burt?*

Boss: *Unfortunately he wasn't as dedicated as I expect from someone working for this company, so I fired him. **Let that be a reminder to the rest of you.***

Questions:

1. Does the highlighted part make perfect sense here and is it natural?
2. Can it stand on its own without adding something to it like... "Let that be a reminder to the rest of you that if you're not dedicated then..."?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer, "Let that be a warning to the rest of you." The use of "reminder" suggests that the boss has done this or something similar before. Of course that is possible: maybe  the boss *has* done this before.

Of course it might be a reminder of something the boss *said* in the past, e.g. "I will fire slackers".

Comment: Could it not be that the boss wants his other employees to remember _**in the future**_ the fact that he has just fired one of them?

Comment: @fev - I understand your point and I know what you mean. However, in that case, I personally expect, "Let that be a future reminder to work hard." or similar. That's what the OP is asking about.